# Cannot convert Spring Boot RestController response to JSON: `No converter found for return value of type: class ...`

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a POJO class and a `RestController` as follows:

`Account.java`

```
public class Account {
    String name;
    String accountId;

    public Account(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.accountId = "";
    }
}
```

`Controller.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AccountServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccountServiceApplication.class, args);
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    Account root() {
        Account a = new Account("john doe");

        return a;
    }
}
```

My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '0.9.6'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web' 
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json'
}
```

When I curl my web app I get this response:

`{"timestamp":"2019-03-09T10:21:29.648+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"No converter found for return value of type: class account.Account","path":"/"}`

I have checked that I have `jackson` in my dependencies.  Shouldn't it automatically convert to JSON?

Comment: Do you have getter and setter in name and accountId in account class?

Comment: Add getters to your Account class. Otherwise Jackson can't marshal an Account.

Comment: Thanks, guys!  That's what it was missing!